# Does the following limit exist??

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Write $$h(x) = \begin{cases} 0 \quad \textrm{if } x \neq 0 \\ 1 \quad \textrm{if } x = 0 \end{cases}$$

$$ g(x) = \left\{ \begin{align} x \sin \left( \tfrac{1}{x} \right) \quad \textrm{if } x \neq 0 \\ 0 \quad \textrm{if } x = 0 \end{align} \right.$$

Claim is $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} (h \circ g)(x)$ does not exist.

However, I believe the limit is zero since: notice if $x \neq 0$, $h(x) = 0$ is zero no matter what $f$ is. Also, if $x  = 0$, then $g=0$ and so $h(g(0)) = h(0) = 1$ and so $\lim_{x \to 0} h(g(x)) = 0$. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You might think again.  Can you find a sequence $x_k$ that satisfies $x_k\rightarrow 0$ but $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}h(x_k)=1$?  Can you find another sequence that satisfies $x_k\rightarrow 0$ but $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}h(x_k)=0$?  If so, the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} h(g(x))$ does not exist.

Comment: I thought under the formal definition of the limit, we are interested in increasing small values of epsilon close to the limit, and for these g is always non zero, therefore h is always zero for any non-zero epsilon - so I think the limit is zero

Comment: Why do you say "for these $g$ is always nonzero"? @AndrewDeighton

Comment: Notice that if $g(x) = 0$, then $h(g(x)) = 0$.

Comment: @michael - I'm wrong, it isn't always zero, it just has limit zero - you are right!

Comment: Oh Michael, YOU might think again. All I have to say is review the definition of limit when $x\rightarrow a$!!! The sequence $x_k$ has to be diferent of the constant sequence $x_k=a$ the existence of limit does not depend on the definition of the function.

Comment: IN my first comment, above, I mean "but $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} h(g(x_k))=1$ and "but $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} h(g(x_k))=0$"

Comment: I did think again - for increasing small $\epsilon$ there has to exist a smaller value with $1 / \epsilon = n\pi$ - making g zero and at that point $h \circ g = 1$  So there is no limit, it flips between 0 and 1 with increasing frequency

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : I think we all had typos in our comments.  Mine wrote "$h(x_k)$" when I meant "$h(g(x_k))$." [I didn't know how to do that circle symbol for composition] Yours wrote "0" when you meant "1."

Comment: @Michael for the record, it's `\circ`

Comment: "if $x \neq 0$, $h(x) = 0$ is zero no matter what $f$ is." Mh, there is no $f$ in the problem, but your claim is wrong: if $f$ has roots, $h(f(x))$ changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

The composite function is given by

$$h(g(x))=\begin{cases}1&,g(x)=0\\\\0&,g(x)\ne 0\end{cases}$$

So, $h$ can equal only $1$ or $0$.

Note that when $\displaystyle x_n=\frac1{n\pi}$, we have $g(x_n)=0$ and $h(g(x_n))=1$.

Then, take $\epsilon=1$ and show that for all $\delta>0$, there exists an $0<|x_n|<\delta$ such that

$$|h(g(x_n))-0|\ge \epsilon=1$$

and another number $x\ne x_n$ with $0<|x|<\delta$ such that

$$|h(g(x))-1|\ge \epsilon=1$$

Comment: I'm guessing the downvoter is Joss, as his/her answer reaches an unusual conclusion that is different from yours (and the number of up/downvotes on his/her answer has not been changed while yours was).  There was another answerer who also said the limit was 0, but that person realized the mistake and deleted after my comments.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle x_n=\frac {1} {n\pi}$ and $ y_n= \frac {2} {(4n+1)\pi}$, where $n \in $ positive integers. Then $\displaystyle x_n, y_n \not= 0, \lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n) =\lim_{n \to \infty}(y_n) = 0, h(g(x_n)) = h(0)=1,$ and $ h(g(y_n)) = h(y_n)=0.$ This shows that $\lim_{x \to 0}(h(g(x))$ doesn't exist.

Comment: My edit was to replace lim with \lim..............+1